# Uso di "dissociarsi"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Leggendo [questo articolo](http://www.ilfoglio.it/economia/2016/12/28/news/voucher-cosa-sono-e-perche-e-un-problema-ampiamente-sopravvalutato-112775/), mi sono imbattuta in questa frase

> Oggi tutti **se ne dissociano**, ma i voucher sono stati approvati e introdotti per legge dal Parlamento

che fa uso del verbo "dissociarsi" in un modo che a me risulta del tutto nuovo. Posso capire il significato della frase, ma non riesco a immaginare come io possa usare questo verbo, "dissociarsi", con un senso simile a quello di questo testo. Potreste farmene qualche esempio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dissociarsi (da qualcuno/qualcosa) è un verbo riflessivo che significa "esprimere disaccordo".

Se non sono d'accordo con una dichiarazione fatta da un'associazione a cui appartengo, posso dire per esempio

> **Mi dissocio** dal comunicato stampa pubblicato ieri.

Oppure, per esempio

> Bersani **si dissocia** dalla linea del Partito Democratico.

Una ricerca su Google per "si dissociano da" trova molti altri esempi.

Un sinonimo è *prendere le distanze da*.

Questo è praticamente l'unico uso che viene fatto del verbo "dissociarsi" --- in particolare, *non* è il contrario di associarsi (non si dice * *la quota di iscrizione è troppo alta, quindi mi dissocio dal club*).

Comment: Ad essere pignoli c'è un altro significato, utilizzato principalmente in [chimica](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociazione_%28chimica%29), ma si tratta di un uso specialistico.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Hai ragione, ma l'uso in chimica non ha un senso simile a quello del brano, che era quello che chiedevo io.

Comment: @Charo Sì, se non era chiaro sono completamente d'accordo con questa risposta, volevo solo chiarificare la prima frase (notando che *prendere le distanze* non è l'unico significato di *dissociarsi*).

Answer (score 2):

Come precisato dal De Mauro si tratta di un'espressione idiomatica che si usa principalmente in riferimento a contesti e motivi di carattere ideologico/politico con l'intento di esprimere il proprio dissenso o disaccordo.

***[Dissociarsi](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/dissociarsi):*** 
v.pronom.intr. (io mi dissòcio).

> - CO ***distaccarsi da altri per motivi ideologici***, dissentire: *mi dissocio dalla decisione della maggioranza*.